# Obtaining different answers when using NDSolve vs ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, parametric-functions

I am obtaining two different answers for a curve when solving the same exact system of differential equations when using NDSolve vs when using ParametricNDSolveValue. Here it is when using NDSolve:

```
h[r_] = 10^(-2); 
boundary1 = 0.5; 
boundary2 = 1; 
\[Mu]1 = 8*10^4; 
\[Mu]2 = 8*10^4; 
p = 1300; 
w = 1.48323; 
nsolution1 = NDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - 
        \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + 
        \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]1*h[r]*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, lt[0.001] == w, 
      lr[0.001] == w, \[Beta][0.001] == 0.001}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}][[1]]; 
radialstretch[(r_)?NumericQ] := lr[r] /. nsolution1
thetastretch[(r_)?NumericQ] := lt[r] /. nsolution1
angle[(r_)?NumericQ] := \[Beta][r] /. nsolution1
radialstretchderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := D[lr[u] /. nsolution1, u] /. u -> r
thetastretchderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := D[lt[u] /. nsolution1, u] /. u -> r
R[(r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch[r]
Rderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := thetastretch[r] + r*thetastretchderivative[r]
f1[(r_)?NumericQ] := -(radialstretch[r]^2 - Rderivative[r]^2)^(1/2)
Z[(r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Re[f1[t]], {t, 0.001, r}]
p1 := ParametricPlot[{R[r], Z[r] + 1}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}, PlotStyle -> Green]
g[r_] := (1/Sqrt[2])*((\[Mu]1/\[Mu]2)*(radialstretch[r]^2 - 1/(radialstretch[r]^2*thetastretch[r]^2)) + ((\[Mu]1 - radialstretch[r]^4*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]1)^2 + 4*radialstretch[r]^4*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]2^2)^(1/2)/(radialstretch[r]^2*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]2))^(1/2)
nsolution2 = Quiet[NDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - 
         \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + 
         \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]2*h[r]*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
       lt[boundary1] == thetastretch[boundary1], lr[boundary1] == g[boundary1], \[Beta][boundary1] == angle[boundary1]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary1, boundary2}][[1]]]; 
radialstretch2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[lr[r] /. nsolution2]
thetastretch2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[lt[r] /. nsolution2]
angle2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[\[Beta][r] /. nsolution2]
radialstretchderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[D[lr[u] /. nsolution2, u] /. u -> r]
thetastretchderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[D[lt[u] /. nsolution2, u] /. u -> r]
R2[(r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch2[r]
Rderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := thetastretch2[r] + r*thetastretchderivative2[r]
f2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[-(radialstretch2[r]^2 - Rderivative2[r]^2)^(1/2)]
Z2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[NIntegrate[Re[f2[t]], {t, boundary1, r}]]
sol2 = Solve[Z2[boundary1] + x2 == Z[boundary1], Plus[x2]]; 
x2 = x2 /. sol2[[1]]; 
y2 := 1 + x2; 
p2 := ParametricPlot[{R2[r], Z2[r] + y2}, {r, boundary1, boundary2}, PlotStyle -> Red]
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: curve shape when using NDSolve]

Now, here it is solving it using ParametricNDSolveValue:

```
h = 1/10^2; 
\[Mu]1 = 8*10^4; 
\[Mu]2 = 8*10^4; 
p = 1300; 
boundary1 = 0.5; 
boundary2 = 1; 
nsolution1 = ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - 
       \[Mu]1*h*r*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]1*h*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h*r*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + 
         (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]1*h*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, lt[0.001] == w, lr[0.001] == w, \[Beta][0.001] == 0.001}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}, {w}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10]; 
radialstretch1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := lr[w][r] /. nsolution1
thetastretch1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := lt[w][r] /. nsolution1
angle1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := \[Beta][w][r] /. nsolution1
radialstretchderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := D[lr[w][t] /. nsolution1, t] /. t -> r
thetastretchderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := D[lt[w][t] /. nsolution1, t] /. t -> r
R1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch1[w, r]
Rderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := thetastretch1[w, r] + r*thetastretchderivative1[w, r]
f1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[radialstretch1[w, r]^2 - Rderivative1[w, r]^2]
Z1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f1[w, r], {t, 0.001, r}]
g1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := (1/Sqrt[2])*((\[Mu]1/\[Mu]2)*(radialstretch1[w, r]^2 - 1/(radialstretch1[w, r]^2*thetastretch1[w, r]^2)) + ((\[Mu]1 - radialstretch1[w, r]^4*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]1)^2 + 4*radialstretch1[w, r]^4*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]2^2)^(1/2)/
      (radialstretch1[w, r]^2*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]2))^(1/2)
nsolution2 = ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - 
       \[Mu]2*h*r*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]2*h*r*Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h*r*Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + 
         (2*Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]2*h*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, lt[boundary1] == thetastretch1[w, boundary1], lr[boundary1] == g1[w, boundary1], \[Beta][boundary1] == angle1[w, boundary1]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary1, boundary2}, {w}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 10]; 
radialstretch2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := lr[w][r] /. nsolution2
thetastretch2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := lt[w][r] /. nsolution2
angle2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := \[Beta][w][r] /. nsolution2
radialstretchderivative2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := D[lr[w][t] /. nsolution2, t] /. t -> r
thetastretchderivative2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := D[lt[w][t] /. nsolution2, t] /. t -> r
R2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch2[w, r]
Rderivative2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := thetastretch2[w, r] + r*thetastretchderivative2[w, r]
f2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[radialstretch2[w, r]^2 - Rderivative2[w, r]^2]
Z2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[w, r], {t, boundary1, r}]
p1 := ParametricPlot[{R1[1.48323, r], Z1[1.48323, r] + 1}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}, PlotStyle -> Green]
Clear[x2]; 
Clear[y2]; 
sol2 = Solve[Z2[1.48323, boundary1] + x2 == Z1[1.48323, boundary1], Plus[x2]]; 
x2 = x2 /. sol2[[1]]; 
y2 = 1 + x2; 
p2 := ParametricPlot[{R2[1.48323, r], Z2[1.48323, r] + y2}, {r, boundary1, boundary2}, PlotStyle -> Red]
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: curve shape when using ParametricNDSolveValue]

As you can see, the equations are exactly the same, the parameters used are exactly the same, however, the results are different. I would love to use ParametricNDSolveValue because it is much more convenient for my code, which is much longer than this, and it works much faster, but I need to first know why it is giving me a different answer. If anyone has any insight, please let me know.

Comment: There are many typos in the code, for example, `h[r]` is not defined for `nsolution1`.

Comment: It was in my notebook, I somehow missed copying it here. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions computed with `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve` are the same as it follows from the test

```
Clear["`*"]

boundary1 = 0.5;
boundary2 = 1;
\[Mu]1 = 8*10^4;
\[Mu]2 = 8*10^4;
p = 1300;
h = 1/10^2;

nsolutionp1 = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
    lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
   p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h*
      Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h*r*
      Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
      Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h*r*
      Sin[\[Beta][
        r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
         r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
           Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 
    0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h*
      Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]1*h*r*
      Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
      Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h*r*
      Cos[\[Beta][
        r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
         r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
           Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]1*
      h*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, lt[0.001] == w, 
   lr[0.001] == w, \[Beta][0.001] == 0.001}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, 
   0.001, boundary1}, {w}]; 
radialstretch1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
 lr[w][r] /. nsolutionp1;
thetastretch1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := lt[w][r] /. nsolutionp1;
angle1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := \[Beta][w][r] /. nsolutionp1;
radialstretchderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
  D[lr[w][t], t] /. t -> r /. nsolutionp1;
thetastretchderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
  D[lt[w][t], t] /. t -> r /. nsolutionp1;
R1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch1[w, r];
Rderivative1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
  thetastretch1[w, r] + r*thetastretchderivative1[w, r];
f1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[
    radialstretch1[w, r]^2 - Rderivative1[w, r]^2];
Z1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[f1[w, r], {t, 0.001, r}];
g1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?
   NumericQ] := (1/
    Sqrt[2])*((\[Mu]1/\[Mu]2)*(radialstretch1[w, r]^2 - 
        1/(radialstretch1[w, r]^2*
           thetastretch1[w, r]^2)) + ((\[Mu]1 - 
            radialstretch1[w, r]^4*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]1)^2 + 
         4*radialstretch1[w, r]^4*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]2^2)^(1/
         2)/(radialstretch1[w, r]^2*thetastretch1[w, r]^2*\[Mu]2))^(1/
     2); nsolutionp2 = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
    lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
   p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h*
      Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h*r*
      Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
      Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h*r*
      Sin[\[Beta][
        r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
         r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
           Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 
    0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h*
      Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]2*h*r*
      Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
      Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h*r*
      Cos[\[Beta][
        r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
         r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
           Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]2*
      h*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
   lt[boundary1] == thetastretch1[w, boundary1], 
   lr[boundary1] == g1[w, boundary1], \[Beta][boundary1] == 
    angle1[w, boundary1]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary1, 
   boundary2}, {w}];
```

To test solutions we plot

```
{test1 = 
  Plot[Evaluate[{lr[w][r], lt[w][r], \[Beta][w][r]} /. 
      w -> 1.48323 /. nsolutionp1], {r, 0.001, boundary1}, 
   PlotLegends -> {lr, lt, \[Beta]}], 
 test2 = Plot[
   Evaluate[{lr[w][r], lt[w][r], \[Beta][w][r]} /. w -> 1.48323 /. 
     nsolutionp2], {r, boundary1, boundary2}, 
   PlotLegends -> {lr, lt, \[Beta]}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

`NDSolve` code

```
Clear[{h, w, f1}]

boundary1 = 0.5;
boundary2 = 1;
\[Mu]1 = 8*10^4;
\[Mu]2 = 8*10^4;
p = 1300;
w = 1.48323; h[r_] := 1/10^2;

nsolution1 = 
  NDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h[r]*
        Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*
        Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
        Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*
        Sin[\[Beta][
          r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
             Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]1*h[r]*
        Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*
        Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
        Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]1*h[r]*r*
        Cos[\[Beta][
          r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
             Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]1*
        h[r]*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, lt[0.001] == w, 
     lr[0.001] == w, \[Beta][0.001] == 0.001}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, 
     0.001, boundary1}][[1]];
radialstretch[(r_)?NumericQ] := lr[r] /. nsolution1
thetastretch[(r_)?NumericQ] := lt[r] /. nsolution1
angle[(r_)?NumericQ] := \[Beta][r] /. nsolution1
radialstretchderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 D[lr[u] /. nsolution1, u] /. u -> r
thetastretchderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 D[lt[u] /. nsolution1, u] /. u -> r
R[(r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch[r]
Rderivative[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 thetastretch[r] + r*thetastretchderivative[r]
f1[(r_)?NumericQ] := -(radialstretch[r]^2 - Rderivative[r]^2)^(1/2)
Z[(r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Re[f1[t]], {t, 0.001, r}]
p1 := ParametricPlot[{R[r], Z[r] + 1}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]
g[r_] := (1/
    Sqrt[2])*((\[Mu]1/\[Mu]2)*(radialstretch[r]^2 - 
        1/(radialstretch[r]^2*
           thetastretch[r]^2)) + ((\[Mu]1 - 
            radialstretch[r]^4*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]1)^2 + 
         4*radialstretch[r]^4*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]2^2)^(1/
         2)/(radialstretch[r]^2*thetastretch[r]^2*\[Mu]2))^(1/2)
nsolution2 = 
  NDSolve[{lt[r] + r*Derivative[1][lt][r] == lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p*r*lt[r]*lr[r]*Cos[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h[r]*
        Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*
        Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
        Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*
        Sin[\[Beta][
          r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
             Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, (-p)*r*lr[r]*lt[r]*Sin[\[Beta][r]] - \[Mu]2*h[r]*
        Cos[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) + \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*
        Derivative[1][\[Beta]][r]*
        Sin[\[Beta][r]]*(lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^2)) - \[Mu]2*h[r]*r*
        Cos[\[Beta][
          r]]*(Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3*Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4*lt[r]^2) + (2*
             Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3*lt[r]^3)) + \[Mu]2*
        h[r]*(lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2*lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     lt[boundary1] == thetastretch[boundary1], 
     lr[boundary1] == g[boundary1], \[Beta][boundary1] == 
      angle[boundary1]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary1, 
     boundary2}][[1]];
radialstretch2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[lr[r] /. nsolution2]
thetastretch2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[lt[r] /. nsolution2]
angle2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[\[Beta][r] /. nsolution2]
radialstretchderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet[D[lr[u] /. nsolution2, u] /. u -> r]
thetastretchderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet[D[lt[u] /. nsolution2, u] /. u -> r]
R2[(r_)?NumericQ] := r*thetastretch2[r]
Rderivative2[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 thetastretch2[r] + r*thetastretchderivative2[r]
f2[(r_)?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet[-(radialstretch2[r]^2 - Rderivative2[r]^2)^(1/2)]
Z2[(r_)?NumericQ] := Quiet[NIntegrate[Re[f2[t]], {t, boundary1, r}]]
sol2 = Solve[Z2[boundary1] + x2 == Z[boundary1], x2];
x2 = x2 /. sol2[[1]];
y2 := 1 + x2;
p2 := ParametricPlot[{R2[r], Z2[r] + y2}, {r, boundary1, boundary2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Now we can compare two solutions as follows

```
{Show[test1, 
  Plot[Evaluate[{lr[r], lt[r], \[Beta][r]} /. nsolution1], {r, 0.001, 
    boundary1}, PlotLegends -> {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, 
      Dashed}}]],
 Show[test2, 
  Plot[Evaluate[{lr[r], lt[r], \[Beta][r]} /. nsolution2], {r, 
    boundary1, boundary2}, PlotLegends -> {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}}]]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Therefore, all discrepancies coming from definitions `p1,p2` and other functions. For example, `Z` and `Z1` are differ, while definitions `f1` are not differ
[image: Figure 3]

We should look what `NIntegrate` doing in two cases. Finally we found out typos in definitions `Z1[w, r], Z2[w,r]`

```
Z1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
      NIntegrate[f1[w, r], {t, 0.001, r}];
Z2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[w, r], {t, boundary1, r}]
```

Obviously it should be

```
Z1[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := 
          NIntegrate[f1[w, t], {t, 0.001, r}];
Z2[(w_)?NumericQ, (r_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[w, t], {t, boundary1, r}]
```

After correction we have same picture for `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve` (dashed lines)
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you see some obvious mistake that I have made when defining the functions using the solutions from ParametricNDSolve? I don't know another way of defining them for them to work as when I do so from NDSolve.

Comment: More precisely, `x2` in two definitions is not the same since   `Z1[1.48323, boundary1]=-0.431163`, while `Z[boundary1]=-0.230469`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help. Since f1 are not different, all the issues have to be due to the integrating of it. Somehow in the second case(the ParametricNDSolve one), using NIntegrate on f1 is doing something different. I will try some stuff and post an update soon.

Comment: @juv95 There is a typo in definition `Z1[w, r]` since you used under `NIntegrate` function `f1[w,r]` instead of  `f1[w,t]`.

Comment: Ahh, that was so careless of me... thank you for pointing it out. Everything is working out well now, except I had to make a change on the definition of Z1. Initially, I had it defined as NIntegrate[f1[w,t],{t,0.001,r}], and that was not working. When I switched it to NIntegrate[f1[w,r],{r,0.001,t}] instead, it works great. I am not sure why that is the case, but I'll mention it here in case it helps anyone in the future.

Comment: @juv95 If my answer is useful, then you can upvote, by clicking on a gray triangle.

Comment: Absolutely, already done! Thanks again.

Comment: @juv95 You are welcome!